# Failed to read key upload from store

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

For 3 days I couldn't solve this issue, I went through several stackoverflow approach and apply the solutions. I change the keystore password, used the full path of the keystore instead od **../** build a **new project** but still, I was unable to create the **app bundle**.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
   > Failed to read key upload from store "/Users/username/Desktop/project/android/app/upload-keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 50s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                            113.0s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: 33


Make sure you are using the right password to open the keystore. I was having this error and turns out I was still using the password from the example code in trusted.load()

Comment: You are using a keystore created with a newer version of keytool (or some other method like openssl) with an older version of java that doesn't understand the MAC. (Older versions of Java only support the SHA1 variant.) Did you, perhaps, create the keystore using Java 17 and running gradle under Java 8 or 11?

Comment: @RichardHeap Thank you for your input you might be right. The java version on my Mac is 18.0.2.1. So how to know the java version of my gradle and how to update it to solve this issue. I am using android studio

Comment: @MilanSurelia Thank you for your input, but as for the password I double-checked several and there's no mistake about it.

Comment: Type in the Mac equivalent of `"\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe" -version` and/or use the `keytool` that's in that same bin folder instead of the v18 one.